# ScrollViewer ScrollBar visibility

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollbar

I'm working with WPF ScrollViewer.

```
<ScrollViewer Name="uiPageScrollViewer" 
              ScrollViewerHorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
...
</ScrollViewer>
```

I'm adding elements to ScrollViewer and `HorizontalScrollBar` is showing in the UI.

When I try to get `uiPageScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` in code behind it returns **`Auto`**.

How can I get `Visibility`? When `HorizontalScrollBar` is showing in UI than it should return Visible else does not matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [ScrollViewer.ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.computedhorizontalscrollbarvisibility(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 5):

As already noted, you are mixing 2 things together: visibility configuration and visibility state:

`ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` (bold is mine):

> Gets or sets a value that indicates **whether** a horizontal ScrollBar should be displayed.

`ScrollViewer.ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility`:

> Gets a value that indicates whether the horizontal ScrollBar is visible.